# Any tools out there that will EXECUTE BPMN 2.0 xml code yet?

Tags: xml, business-process-management

Business Process Modeling Notation with version 2.0, an international standard formally approved by OMG, creates XML code that is generated when a person creates a process model in a process modeling tool...like Visio with ITP-Commerce BPM 2.0 add-in.

I would like to know if any of you gurus out there have or can create a tool that will take the XML code and EXECUTE it.

Anyone?

Thanks very much,

Randy

Answer (score 1):

Popular BPMN 2.0 compliant open-source engines:

- http://www.activiti.org/
- http://www.jboss.org/jbpm
- http://www.bonitasoft.com/

A commercial engine:

- http://www.activevos.com/products

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Activiti](http://activiti.org).

Answer (score 0):

Consider Roubroo - the only BPMN 2.0 engine written after the specification was beta and by the folks that actively wrote the specification. If your tool / vendor suggests to stay away from IOR gateway - he is asking you to use the technology of 1990s. 
No BPMN 2.0 engine is complete if it does not support token flow semantics and there are very few that really do. There are quite a few old engines wrapped under the new paint.